# How to reload nodes in Node-RED without restarting?

Tags: node.js, node-red

Currently every time I make a change to a Node-RED node during development it requires stopping and starting the server to apply changes. This is even required if something minor changes, like just editing a label.

How can I reload nodes in Node-RED without restarting the server? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it even possible?

No - you must restart Node-RED to pickup any changes.

You could use a tool such as `nodemon` to watch for changes on your node files and automatically restart Node-RED. That helps get your changes picked-up with less manual intervention.

Comment: Sorry for leaving it a bit open, although you're probably the person with the most knowledge about Node-RED; having written most of it. Is it not technically possible at all without a major rewrite? If so, I will accept your answer soonish. :)

Comment: If it was possible with the current codebase I would have said so in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implement watch mecanisum with nodemon

```bash
npm i nodemon -D
```

nodemon.json

```json
{
  "watch": ["src/**"],
  "exec": "node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js $FLOWS",
  "ext": "js, json, ts, proto, html",
  "ignore": "src/**/*.test.ts, src/**/*.spec.ts"
}
```

now just launch `nodemon` command